# Beforeunload & jQuery Event Delegation causing issues in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

This one is tough, so please bear with me as I "try" to explain it...

My customer wanted a warning message to display when people clicked away from dirty "forms"...so I created something based-on the "BeforeUnload" event.  Yes, there are online widgets to do this, but the ones I've seen rely-on the FORM element existing...and...not all forms in the app have a FORM element (they just use API).

In Chrome, the "BeforeUnload" widget works great.  However, Internet Explorer keeps giving me an error in jQuery.  And, I cant seem to figure out the problem.

**So, the questions are things like...**
 - Is there something wrong with my event delegation setups?
 - Is my approach incorrect?

Things like that...any ideas are welcome.

**The console error is...**

> SCRIPT 16389: Unspecified Error jquery-2.2.4.js (7841,6)

**The console error resolves to...**
The value of 'type' is 'submit'...which makes sense.

```
// If nobody prevented the default action, do it now
if ( !onlyHandlers && !event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {

    if ( ( !special._default ||
        special._default.apply( eventPath.pop(), data ) === false ) &&
        acceptData( elem ) ) {

        if ( ontype && jQuery.isFunction( elem[ type ] ) && !jQuery.isWindow( elem ) ) {

            tmp = elem[ ontype ];

            if ( tmp ) {
                elem[ ontype ] = null;
            }

            jQuery.event.triggered = type;
            elem[ type ](); //*** <-- IT BREAKS HERE ***
            jQuery.event.triggered = undefined;

            if ( tmp ) {
                elem[ ontype ] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

**THE SUBMIT BUTTON ELEMENT:**
The default type for a BUTTON is 'Submit'...so it makes sense jQuery would see it as so.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-new view-state-tracking-cancel">
    <span>Save</span>
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

**THE SUBMIT BUTTON EVENT:**
jQuery re-wraps the event it passes-in & takes care of "preventDefault" variations between browsers.

```
btnCreateNew: function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // Kendo Validation
    that.setup.validator.save();

    var isValid = dictionary.instances.validator.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
        return false;
    }

    dictionary.elements.form.submit();
}
```

**THE CONTROLLER CODE:**
This should be self-explanatory...

```
window.etp.controllers = window.etp.controllers || {};

// DIALOG
window.etp.controllers.ViewStateController = (function ($) {

    function ViewStateController() {

        var that = this;
        var initialize = function () {

            // MARKED: Buttons
            $('.view-state-tracking-cancel').on('click', function (e) {
                that.status.isDirty = false;
            });

            // Textboxes, KendoDatePickers, KendoComboBox
            $('input[type=text]:not(.view-state-tracking-omit)').on('change', function (e) {
                that.status.isDirty = true;
            });

            // RadioButtons
            $('[type=radio]:not(.view-state-tracking-omit)').on('change', function (e) {
                that.status.isDirty = true;
            });

            // CheckBoxes
            $('[type=checkbox]:not(.view-state-tracking-omit)').on('change', function (e) {
                that.status.isDirty = true;
            });

            // TextAreas
            $('textarea:not(.view-state-tracking-omit)').on('change', function (e) {
                that.status.isDirty = true;
            });
        };

        this.status = {
            isDirty: false
        };
        this.reset = function () {
            that.isDirty = false;
        };

        initialize();
    }

    return ViewStateController;
})(jQuery);
```

**THE 'EVENT LISTENER' CODE:**
This code loads before all other, but after jQuery. Additionally, you can no longer set a custom message, so I leave it blank.

```
window.etp.viewState = null;

window.onload = function () {

    // User Message for Unsaved Changes
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if (window.etp.viewState == null) {
            return undefined;
        }

        if (!window.etp.viewState.status.isDirty) {
            return undefined;
        }

        var confirmationMessage = '';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; // Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage; // Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    });
};
```

**THE 'CONSOLE.LOG' in IE:**
I added logging & found the following...

- RUNNING - ViewStateController.initialize()
- SETTING - ViewStateController.Textboxes.isDirty = TRUE
- SCRIPT 16389: Unspecified Error jquery-2.2.4.js (7841,6)

**THE 'CONSOLE.LOG' in CHROME:**
I added logging & found the following...

- RUNNING - ViewStateController.initialize()
- SETTING - ViewStateController.Textboxes.isDirty = TRUE
- SETTING - ViewStateController.Textboxes.isDirty = FALSE

**VERSIONS:**
I cannot update jQuery yet because of the customers (in-house) Framework requirements...

- jQuery 2.2.4
- IE 11

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you tried with a newer version of jQuery? 2.2.4 is quite old now